# Swift(iOS) inserting UIImage array to subview?

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, uiimage

Swift(iOS) problem: how can I insert UIImage array to subview? I wanted to make a horizontal scroll view in view controller with very little experience with swift. Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configurePageControl()

    var pictures:[UIImage] = [ ]
    pictures.append(UIImage(named: "SOVERMENT1.jpg")!)
    pictures.append(UIImage(named: "SOVERMENT2.jpg")!)
    pictures.append(UIImage(named: "SOVERMENT3.jpg")!)
    pictures.append(UIImage(named: "SOVERMENT4.jpg")!)



    scrollView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    for index in 0..<4 {

        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
        self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true

        var subView = UIView(frame: frame)
        **subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage : ]**
        self.scrollView.addSubview(subView)
    }
```

This is first problem. How can I insert pictures into subview.backgroundColor? I searched it for 1~2hours, but I couldn't find any answer.

```
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 4, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
    pageControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("changePage:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


}


func configurePageControl() {


   ** self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pictures.count **
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
```

And here. Why array pictures cannot be counted?

Answer (score 5):

Unless these are repeatable pattern images, I think you want to use a UIImageView. I also don't think you need to use a UIPageControl, because you're only using one UIViewController. You can say something like:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        var pictures:[UIImage] = [ ]
        pictures.append(UIImage(named: "SOVERMENT1.jpg")!)
        pictures.append(UIImage(named: "SOVERMENT2.jpg")!)
        pictures.append(UIImage(named: "SOVERMENT3.jpg")!)
        pictures.append(UIImage(named: "SOVERMENT4.jpg")!)



        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(pictures.count), scrollView.frame.size.height)
        for index in 0..<pictures.count {
            var frame = CGRectZero
            frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
            scrollView.pagingEnabled = true

            var subView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
            subView.image = pictures[index]
            subView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            self.scrollView.addSubview(subView)
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use UICollectionView for such purposes

Answer (score 0):

For setting the backgroundColor call the UIColor initializer:

```
for picture in pictures {
    subView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: picture)
}
```